# iOS Promo Codes and app updates

Tags: ios, promotion-code, app-update

If a user has downloaded a 'Pending Developer Release' version (v1.0.0) of an iOS app via a promo code and we create a subsequent build (v1.0.1), will this automatically update v1.0.0 users apps?

If v1.0.1 is still 'Pending Developer Release' and isn't Live then how would it update (as it wouldn't be available to update from the App Store app on the device) without providing a new redeem code?

Maybe I've answered my own question, but seeking confirmation.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

My experience with the same situation is: no, it does not update it. It doesn't happen automatically and there is nowhere the user can go to update it manually. You have to give the user another code to get it to update.  And Apple is very stingy with those codes, even for free apps.